# How do I access the original method of a monkeypatched method in Perl?

Tags: perl, monkeypatching

I'm trying to [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) a Perl class: I want to change the behavior of an existing method.

[This node on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=694332) shows how to *add* a function to an existing class. I found that this pattern can also be used to provide a new implementation for an existing function.

However, I'd like to know how to call the original function.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
use ExistingClass;

# TODO: Somehow rename existingFunction() to oldExistingFunction().

sub ExistingClass::existingFunction {
    my $self = shift;

    # New behavior goes here.
    $self->oldExistingFunction(@_); # Call old behavior.
    # More new behavior here.
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Typeglob assignment

```
*ExistingClass::oldExistingFunction = *ExistingClass::existingFunction;
```

Quick and dirty.  This aliases all `existingFunction` symbols to `oldExistingFunction`.  This includes the sub you're interested in, but also any scalars, arrays, hashes, handles that might happen to have the same name.

- Advantages: no thinking, it just works.  "quick"
- Disadvantages: "dirty"

### Coderef assignment

```
*ExistingClass::oldExistingFunction = \&ExistingClass::existingFunction;
# or something using *ExistingClass::symbol{CODE}
```

That one only aliases the sub.  It's still done in the package stash, so the `oldExistingFunction` symbol is globally visible, which might or might not be what you want.  Probably not.

- Advantages: that aliasing doesn't 'leak' to other variable types.
- Disadvantages: more thinking, more typing.  A lot more thinking if going for the *...{CODE} syntax (I personnally don't use it every day)

### Lexical coderef

```
my $oldFunction = \&ExistingClass::existingFunction;
```

Using `my` keeps a reference to the old function that is only visible to the currrent block/file.  There is no way for external code to get hold of it without your help anymore.  Mind the calling convention:

```
$self->$oldFunction(@args);
$oldFunction->($self, @args);
```

- Advantages: no visibility issues anymore
- Disadvantages: harder to get right

### Moose

See [jrockway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575710/monkey-patching-in-perl-how-to-access-original-method/576425#576425).  It's got to be The Right Way, since there's no mucking around with globs and/or references anymore, but I don't know it enough to explain it.

Comment: Also note it aliases variables with the same name (scalars, arrays...) as well.  I figured it wouldn't be a problem in your case, but it can be made more strict if needed.

Comment: Also note that if you didn't want to expose the old function to users of your class, you can store the whole thing in a scalar.

Comment: To make it more strict, you'd do *... = \&...; instead of = *...;

Comment: I just integrated what I could from your comments.  If someone wants to detail (edit or comment) the *...{CODE} one a bit, please do!  I don't have enough time to dig the subject.  (plus, I don't like magic words :)

Comment: If all you want from Moose is overriding a method, you're using too much technology. Moose is fine if you are using it for everything else, but a dumb choice if you are only handpicking from its features features.

Answer (score 8):

You should use [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) or [Class::Method::Modifiers](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Method::Modifiers).

In that case, you can just say:

```
around 'some_method' => sub {
    my ($orig, $self, @args) = @_;
    # ... before original ...
    $self->$orig(@_);
    # ... after original ...
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides the other answers, look at modules such as:

- [Sub::Override](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Sub-Override)
- [Hook::LexWrap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Hook-LexWrap)

I also talk about this in the "Dynamic Languages" chapter in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/).

Answer (score 3):

Just copy it to a lexical variable and call it.

```
my $existing_function_ref = \&ExistingClass::existingFunction;
*ExistingClass::existingFunction = sub { 
    my $self = shift;
    $self->go_and_do_some_stuff();
    my @returns = $existing_function_ref->( $self, @_ );
    $self->do_some_stuff_with_returns( @returns );
    return wantarray ? @returns : shift @returns;
};
```

If you would feel better about it with OO-syntax, you could create a `UNIVERSAL::apply` method (or at any base class you chose).

```
sub UNIVERSAL::apply { 
    my ( $self, $block ) = splice( @_, 0, 2 );
    unshift @_, $self;
    goto &$block;
}
```

That way you can call it like this:

```
my @returns = $self->apply( $existing_function_ref, @_ );
```

Answer (score 2):

[Memoize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Memoize) is a good example of this.

Answer (score 1):

For [Moose](http://metacpan.org/module/Moose) classes, you can just [do what jrockway says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576425/40468); for non-Moose classes, do this:

```
use Class::MOP ();
use ExistingClass;

Class::MOP::Class->initialize('ExistingClass')->add_around_method_modifier(
    existingFunction => sub {
        my $orig = shift;

        # new behaviour goes here

        # call old behaviour
        my $result = $orig->(@_);

        # more new behaviour goes here
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

As an alterative, what's wrong with:

```
package NewClass;
use base qw/ExistingClass/;

sub existingFunction {
# ....
}

sub oldExistingFunction {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->SUPER::existingFunction(@_);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if some code that you don't maintain calls ExistingClass->existingFunction();  It would still call the original method and not the modified one.  You could monkey patch that too, but it might end up being a mess of monkey patches.